Unable to get custom config working in MySQL container
I'm trying to get the MySQl 8.4 official image working. I have the following my.cnf:
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password
# query_cache_size=16M

# MY-013360 - mysql_native_password notice
log_error_suppression_list='MY-013360'

I have it mounted into docker as
volumes:
  - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf

But when I go into the mysql cli, show global variables like 'log_error_suppression_list'; returns empty. When I go into my container, I can see the file. How do I get my custom conf file working? I know I can pass it as params, which I've gotten working, but am not sure why the file variant isn't working.
